# Not able to access elasticsearch Kopf

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I'm trying to install elasticsearch-kopf

When I run:

```
plugin -install lmenezes/elasticsearch-kopf
```

I get:

```
-> Installing lmenezes/elasticsearch-kopf...
Failed to install lmenezes/elasticsearch-kopf, reason: plugin directory /usr/local/var/lib/elasticsearch/plugins/kopf already exists. To update the plugin, uninstall it first using --remove lmenezes/elasticsearch-kopf command
```

But, when I try to access Kopf in

```
http://localhost:9200/_plugin/kopf/
```

I get this:

```
This localhost page can’t be found
```

But when I access elasticsearch at:

```
http://localhost:9200/
```

I get:

```
{
  "name" : "Rachel van Helsing",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "2.3.1",
    "build_hash" : "bd980929010aef404e7cb0843e61d0665269fc39",
    "build_timestamp" : "2016-04-04T12:25:05Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "5.5.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says it all

> Failed to install lmenezes/elasticsearch-kopf, reason: plugin directory /usr/local/var/lib/elasticsearch/plugins/kopf already exists. To update the plugin, uninstall it first using --remove lmenezes/elasticsearch-kopf command

So either remove it first with

```
plugin --remove lmenezes/elasticsearch-kopf
```

Or simply delete the `kopf` folder

```
rm -rf /usr/local/var/lib/elasticsearch/plugins/kopf
```

Then you should be able to install it properly.